# Email task to notify error should be added in error handling or error output?

Tags: ssis

I have all tasks in a sequence container.

If there is an error in any task inside the container then I want to send an email. Where is the ideal place to have the send email task:

1. Add email task to the error output (red line) of the sequence contianer.
2. Or add email task to error handling of the sequence container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Event Handler inside the Data Flow Task in a specific Package :
[image]

So when calling the Data Flow Task inside the the container, the Event Handler will be invoked once there is an error.